# Render angle is different to viewport

Tags: rendering

I am new to Blender and I am rendering a title animation. I see that the angle of the render is different to the viewport angle. The angle of the render is 45 degrees, just like the camera angle and I want it to be like my front view, just flat.  Can you advise how to change settings to get a render with the same angle as the viewport please? Thanks a lot for your answer. Best regards, Maarten Fenenga.

Comment: Hi. Please use the edit button below your question to add images that give us a better idea about your problem. Also, please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) to learn how you could help us to give good answers.

Answer (score 1):

If don't want to have perspective effects you change your camera to orthogonal.

Comment: Hello Luca, Thanks very much for your quick reply. I did change to orthogonal and I did this by going to the Scene collection and click on camera, then the camera icon appears in the tool box under the scene collection. I was able to scale the ortho to the right size as well. Thanks again!